# Как добавить последний элемент вложенного кортежа в предыдущий вложенный кортеж?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuple

Есть список кортежей:

```
my_list[('str', 'str', int1), ('str', 'str', int2), ('str','str', int3)...]
```

Необходимо взять последний элемент (int) и добавить в предыдущий кортеж?
На выходе чтоб получилось:

```
my_list[('str', 'str', int1, int2), ('str', 'str', int2, int3)...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в кортеж что-либо невозможно, поскольку кортеж - это неизменяемая структура данных, можно только создать новый.

Вот пример одного из решений:

```
list_of_tuples = [('str', 'str', 'int1'), ('str', 'str', 'int2'), ('str', 'str', 'int3')]

new_list_of_tuples = [list_of_tuples[x] + (list_of_tuples[x + 1][-1],) for x in range(len(list_of_tuples) - 1)]

print(new_list_of_tuples)
```

Вывод:

```
[('str', 'str', 'int1', 'int2'), 
 ('str', 'str', 'int2', 'int3')]
```

Comment: Павел "палундра", если по твоему методу, последний кортеж выбывает из-за того, что нет для него данных для добавления, можно как-то дополнить если нет данных для добавления вставляло что-то произвольное, например None?  Заменил кортежи на списки.

Comment: @Max_Filatov можно просто к уже созданному списку кортежей отдельно добавить последний с добавленным элементом `None`: `new_list_of_tuples.append(list_of_tuples[-1] + (None,))`

Comment: Фух, спасиб еще раз, сработало.